# Choosing a PIL.ImageFont by font name rather than filename, and cross-platform font

Tags: python, fonts, python-imaging-library

`ImageFont.truetype` requires a filename to work, such as:

```
font = ImageFont.truetype("ariblk.ttf")  # Arial Black
```

Is there a way with `PIL`, to load a font by name, rather than filename?

Context: I would like to load a bold (with heavy weight) sans-serif font, that would work on any platform Windows, Linux, Mac.

I don't think `ImageFont.truetype("ariblk.ttf")` will work cross-platform, is it possible to load it with `ImageFont.truetype("Arial Black")` or, better, `ImageFont.truetype("sans-serif;bold")` that would work on all platforms?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of Pillow's [`ImageFont`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html) module, there's no such an option, no.

A handy workaround might be to use Matplotlib's [`font_manager`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html) module for that: *A module for finding, managing, and using fonts across platforms.* Using the [`FontProperties`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontProperties) and [`findfont`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/font_manager_api.html#matplotlib.font_manager.FontManager.findfont), you should get the a valid path to a font with the given properties, which you can then use in the common `ImageFont.truetype` call.

Here's a small example, which runs perfectly fine on my Windows machine. Unfortunately, I don't have any other OS nearby to test.

```py
from matplotlib import font_manager
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

font = font_manager.FontProperties(family='sans-serif', weight='bold')
file = font_manager.findfont(font)
print(file)

img = Image.new('RGB', (400, 300), (255, 255, 255))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

font = ImageFont.truetype(file, 48)
draw.text((20, 20), 'Hello World', font=font, fill=(255, 0, 0))

img.save('test.png')
```

The `print` output:

```
...\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf
```

The image output:

[image: Output]

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
Matplotlib:    3.3.4
Pillow:        8.1.0
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Great suggestion 

Comment: Works for me on OSX. IMHO this answer should be accepted

Comment: It works for me on OSX 13.6 with chip M2

Answer (score 2):

The top answer by HansHirse is fantastic but just to add to it for anyone still looking, you can also use matplotlib.font_manager to find specific fonts:

```
from matplotlib import font_manager

#print all available fonts 
print(font_manager.get_font_names())


#Find the path for a specific font:
file = font_manager.findfont('Helvetica Neue')

#Load the font to pillow
font = ImageFont.truetype(file, 20)

#draw text onto image using pillow:
draw.text((20, 20), 'Hello World', font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0))
```

If you are particularly worried about fonts not being available on other systems but would like to keep your default, you can combine these in a try...except... cause:

```
try:
    file = font_manager.findfont('Helvetica Neue')
    font = ImageFont.truetype(file, fontsize)
except:
    font_search = font_manager.FontProperties(family='sans-serif', weight='normal')
    file = font_manager.findfont(font_search)
    font = ImageFont.truetype(file, fontsize)
```

This way you can be confident you either get the default font or a similar font if it is not being available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimPIL-Font](https://github.com/OneMadGypsy/SimPIL-Font/tree/main).

###### Basic Usage

```
from simpilfont import SimPILFont, FONTMAP

#load .ttf fonts from a directory and all sub-directories
FONTMAP(fontdir='path/to/fonts') 

text = "Hello World"

#load/configure font
sf  = SimPILFont('DejaVu Sans 16 condensed bold oblique')

#get ImageFont
ttf = sf.font

#measure text
x,y,w,h = sf.bbox(text)

img  = Image.new("RGB", (w-x, h-y), color="black")
dctx = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

dctx.text((-x, -y), text, font=ttf, fill="white")

img.show()
del dctx
```